# Convert HTML to ADF (Atlassian Document Format) markup?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

**myHTML**

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "type": "doc",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "heading",
            "attrs": {
                "level": 1
            },
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Hello World"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There a RUST code repo available

https://github.com/wouterken/htmltoadf

before I start learning the code and manually convert this huge lines, is there any simple way to achieve this ?

Options like :

1. Directly use wiki markup editor in LWC cmp?
2. Any rest public/paid endpoint to return HTML to ADF ?
3. Any ready convertor for LWC or Apex ?

Comment: If you haven't found anything in your research, you'll probably have to build it yourself.